# Drools rules from same package but different kbases are executed in a test, although they shouldn't

Tags: drools

I have two kbases, each refer to the same package, but different drools rule templates(.drt). Each .drt file refer to the same .xls file. When I run tests separately, everything is fine. But when I run whole test in a single run, rules from other .drt files from the same package get activated. If rule was never used, it would not get activated. Once rule is used, it will be activated in other ksessions, where they shouldn't.

I tried to seperate everything into different packages, it works fine. But I don't want to duplicate xls, since it will be modified by not techy users.

Here is the kmodule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <kbase name="prsGrass" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream"
           packages="prsGrass, autograder">                    
        <ruleTemplate dtable="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/autograders.xls"
                      template="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/soilExcavation/soilExcavation.drt"
                      row="6" col="1"/>
        <ruleTemplate dtable="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/autograders.xls"
                      template="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/soilExcavation/setExcavationSoilCoef.drt"
                      row="13" col="26"/>                                                                                                                               
        <ksession name="prsGrassCutKS" type="stateful" default="false"/>
    </kbase> 

    <kbase name="autograderLeveling" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream"
           packages="autograder, expert">
        <ruleTemplate dtable="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/autograders.xls"
                      template="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/leveling.drt"
                      row="6" col="1"/>
        <ruleTemplate dtable="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/autograders.xls"
                      template="com/esteam8/nikolay/expert/equipment/autograder/setSoilCoef.drt"
                      row="6" col="26"/>                                                                                                                                     
        <ksession name="autograderLevelingKS" type="stateful" default="false"/>
    </kbase>

</kmodule>
```

And the tests

```
public class PavementTest {

    @Test
    public void prsGrassCutTest() {
        KieSession session = Expert.create("prsGrassCutKS")
            .work("XX-XXXX-X9", "природно-растительный слой срезка", "1", "m^2")
            .parameter("SOIL-GROUP", "3")
            .and()
            .build();

        session.fireAllRules();

        session.dispose();
        System.out.println("###################################################################################");
    }


    @Test
    public void autograderLevelingTest() {
        KieSession session = Expert.create("autograderLevelingKS")
            .work("XX-XXXX-X12", "Планировка площадей автогрейдером", "1", "m^2")
            .parameter("SOIL-GROUP", "3")
            .and()
            .build();

        session.fireAllRules();
        session.dispose();
        System.out.println("###################################################################################");
    }

}
```

Here is the results from console

```
Soil Excavation
LABOR, Машинист автогрейдера (Разряд 8), E1, Soil1
EQUIPMENT, Автогрейдер XCMG GR215, Soil1, null
AUTOGRADERS, Soil2, Soil1
###################################################################################
Leveling
LABOR, Машинист автогрейдера (Разряд 8), E1, Soil1
LABOR, Машинист автогрейдера (Разряд 8), E1, Soil1
EQUIPMENT, Автогрейдер XCMG GR215, Soil1, null
AUTOGRADERS, Leveling2, Soil1
AUTOGRADERS, Soil2, Soil1
###################################################################################
```

From the console you can notice that in the second test there are two `AUTOGRADERS` and `LABOR`. There should be only one. In addition, those AUTOGRADERS should not have anything related to soil, since it is leveling work. In the second test .drt with rules for "soil" rules got activated with "leveling" .drt. So, two .drts got overlapped.

Here is github repo for those who want to reproduce an example
https://github.com/Kusbek/myProject